# Not able to dynamically build svg path react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm building a custom bottomnavbar for my app, and I'm running into a problem with linking the svg icons. Here is my code:

```
// Imports
class MainTabNavigation extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const navigationOptions = ['Dashboard','Status','Referrals','More'];
    return(
      <View style={styles.navBar}>
      {
        navigationOptions.map(nav => {
          const lowerCaseString = nav.toLowerCase();
          const svgPath = `../../assets/icons/${lowerCaseString}.svg`;
            if (this.props.navigation.isFocused(nav)) {
              return(
              <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.tab,styles.focused]} onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate(nav)}}>
                <SvgUri source={require(svgPath)} />
                <Text style={styles.captionStyle}>nav</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              );
            } else {
              return(
              <TouchableOpacity style={styles.tab} onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate({nav})}}>
                <SvgUri source={require(svgPath)} />
                <Text style={styles.captionStyle}>{nav}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              );
            }
        })
      }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

// Styles

const NavigationConnected = withNavigation( MainTabNavigation );
export { NavigationConnected as MainTabNavigation };
```

And the error message is very strange. The error message says:

```
calls to `require` expect exactly 1 string literal argument, but this was found: `require(svgPath)`.
```

What I can't understand is that `svgPath` is literally (excuse the pun) one string literal. I understand that I'm concatenating the string, but it is still just one string literal. So my question is two fold:
1. **Why is the variable `svgPath` not one string literal?**
2. **How can I dynamically build my svg paths through my map() call?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work, the image name in require has to be known statically.

```
// GOOD
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />;

// BAD
var icon = this.props.active ? 'my-icon-active' : 'my-icon-inactive';
<Image source={require('./' + icon + '.png')} />;

// GOOD
var icon = this.props.active
  ? require('./my-icon-active.png')
  : require('./my-icon-inactive.png');
<Image source={icon} />;
```

ref: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html